# How to add backdrop / esc/ headerclose triggers on bootstrap-vue modal?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

In my project I am using the bootstrap-vue modal. Now I need to add validation for when a user closes the modal. There should be a confirmation question, "Are you sure you want to close without saving?"

The `ok` and `cancel` button triggers work well, but when I tried the same with the <kbd>esc</kbd> key and clicking on the backdrop, but neither of them work. I see in the docs that I can use them https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal/

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <b-btn v-b-modal.modal1>Launch demo modal</b-btn>
  <b-modal id="modal1" title="Bootstrap-Vue" @headerclose="confirmBeforeHide"
    @esc="confirmBeforeHide">
    <p class="my-4">QQ</p>
  </b-modal>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    confirmBeforeHide(e) {
        alert('hi')
    }
  },
})
```

CSS:

```
#app {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 450px;
}
```

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3oxwp94y/)

Comment: Cleaned up the grammar a bit and improved the formatting. Added code so readers don't have to go to the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is @hide to place of esc/headerclose/backdrop